# How to implement PropertyDefiner for logback to access multiple properties

Tags: logback

I would like to define some properties in my logback.xml config file and saw that by implementing the [PropertyDefiner](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly) was a great way to set properties in a customizable way.

After starting to implement it I began to wonder how to access the value of the *name* attribute of the  element within the  tag. I'm not seeing anyway to do this and I'm scratching my head. Would this PropertyDefiner really make you create a new implementation for every single property? Why not just hard code it? I didn't see much discussion about this out on the web.

I hope I'm just not seeing it and that the brains of stackoverflow can help me out. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

I found this [discussion](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2010-November/001941.html): essentially the same question is asked, but no answer was returned.

fyi: I want to customize how I get my properties because I am pulling it from a database. I have a helper class which pulls the properties in on server startup. These properties vary based on environment (dev, test, prod, etc.)

Comment: When you say "how to access the key used in the tag" you mean "how to access the value of the name attribute of the <define> element. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of logback version 1.0.6, the value of the *name* attribute cannot be accessed directly. However, nothing prevents you from passing the value of the *name* attribute in a property of your choice. Example:

```
<define name="rootLevel" class="Your.PropertyDefiner">
  <myKey>rootLevel</myKey>
</define>
```

where `myKey` is a property of `Your.PropertyDefiner`. For example:

```
class Your.PropertyDefiner implements PropertyDefiner {   
  String myKey; 
  public void setMyKey(String k) {
    this.myKey= k;   
  }
  public String getPropertyValue() {
    return ...   
  }  
}
```

Joran, logback's configuration framework, takes care of the wiring. Joran will inject the value of the *myKey* element into the *myKey* property of `Your.PropertyDefiner`. If you are curious about the technical details, see the documentation on [implicit actions](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html#implicit) and [implicit actions in practice](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html#iaPractice).

Comment: So in this case would the setMyKey method be automatically called before getPropertyValue? It looks like magic. Is there documentation on this? Also, it looks like the method setMyKey would need to match to whatever that tag is named in the config file (i.e. if the tag is "aProperty" like on the logback website, then the method would be "setAProperty"). Is this right?

Comment: Updated my answer above to mention implicit actions. At this stage, I suggest you just try to write your own PropertyDefiner class and see how it goes.

Comment: In my case I had to switch the return type of `setMyKey` from `String` to `void` in order to make it work.