# Must multiple Logback PropertyDefiner implementations be created to pull in multiple properties?

Tags: properties, logback

I am able to use a Logback [PropertyDefiner](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly) to access a single property from a logback.xml configuration file.  If I have 3 properties to access, I am currently using 3 separate implementations of PropertyDefiner (one for each property).

Is there a way to access multiple properties from a single PropertyDefiner implementation?  Or perhaps there is another interface that supports multiple properties?

I want to be be able to use properties to plugin different values, based on environment (dev, ist, uat, perf, prod) for various logging configurations (context name, log levels, appender file names, file sizes, etc.).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370666/how-to-implement-propertydefiner-for-logback-to-access-multiple-properties), which is similar, but did not answer the question of how to access multiple properties.

Comment: Could you detail on what the properties are and what do you plan to do with them? Based on that we can think if there are other solutions. The PropertyDefiner solution seems to work for only one property.

Comment: I updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a [PropertyDefiner](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/PropertyDefiner.html) implementation class.  The [PropertyDefinerBase](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/PropertyDefinerBase.html) implementation is already provided.

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase;

public class LoggingPropertiesDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {

  private static Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    properties.put("encoderPattern", "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%n");
    properties.put("maxFileSize", "50MB");
    properties.put("rootLogLevel", "INFO");
  }

  private String propertyLookupKey;

  public void setPropertyLookupKey(String propertyLookupKey) {
    this.propertyLookupKey = propertyLookupKey;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPropertyValue() {
    //TODO In the real world, get properties from a properties loader.
    return properties.get(propertyLookupKey);
  }
}
```

In the logback.xml, use the same PropertyDefiner class for each property.  Provide a different lookup key for each:

```
<define name="encoderPattern" class="foo.bar.LoggingPropertiesDefiner">
    <propertyLookupKey>encoderPattern</propertyLookupKey>
</define>

<define name="maxFileSize" class="foo.bar.LoggingPropertiesDefiner">
    <propertyLookupKey>maxFileSize</propertyLookupKey>
</define>

<define name="rootLogLevel" class="foo.bar.LoggingPropertiesDefiner">
    <propertyLookupKey>rootLogLevel</propertyLookupKey>
</define>
```

Reference the property names in the logback.xml:

```
<root level="${rootLogLevel}">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

Comment: This is an extraordinarily helpful suggestion, that is surprisingly not covered anywhere else. It's definitely counter-intuitive when you spend too much time looking at the logback docs on this subject ... yet it's a really clean solution, esp. when you're just pulling values from a properties file. Thank you chad!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the property resource support from logback

logback.properties

```
mode=prod
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <property resource="logback.properties" />

    <if condition='property("mode").equals("prod")'>
        <then>
            <include file="logback-prod.xml" />
        </then>
    </if>
    <if condition='property("mode").equals("dev")'>
        <then>
            <include resource="logback-dev.xml" />
        </then>
    </if>
</configuration>
```

logback-prod.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
          <File>${MYAPP_HOME}/myApp.log</File>
          <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <FileNamePattern>myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
          <MaxHistory>2</MaxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
          <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
          </layout>
    </appender> 

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

logback-dev.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
          <File>${MYAPP_HOME}/myApp.log</File>
          <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <FileNamePattern>myApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
          <MaxHistory>2</MaxHistory>
          </rollingPolicy>
          <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
          </layout>
    </appender> 


    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

More detailed explaination [here](http://blog.patouchas.net/technology/logging-with-logback-and-external-configuration/).

Does that help to resolve your problem?

Comment: I looked at the property resource support, but was looking for a way to provide a hook into a java class, so I could perform property lookups.  I found a way to use a single PropertyDefiner class to expose multiple properties. I'll add a separate answer showing that.  Thanks for your help!